# iphone ui date picker

Tags: iphone, xcode, datepicker

I have a problem with datepicker.

I would like to change the black/grey boarder surrounding the spindle to a transparent colour.i want to clear the border colour of the picker i want to display only pickerview without border is that possible to clear the border colour.
    please suggest me.

thanks..!
[picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w69D6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to Delete it. 
But in one of my apps I just created an background image in photoshop with a transparent area in the middle of it in the size of the picker.

good luck

Comment: how can we change that..i have uploaded the picture i want to change the border colour in to backgroung colour.please check it and suggest me..

Comment: As me and @MHC told you. you can not totally delete the border. you can just cover it with an other image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it.

If you really want that effect, you may want to put an image on **top** of the picker view, with the center of the image (in the shape of the spindle) has the alpha of 0. Depending on what is shown on the 'pane' area of the picker this may be successful, but I would ask myself if I really need that first...